# How to disable autorefresh on Android?

Tags: root-access, settings, lineageos, 9.0-pie, resurrection-remix-os

I'm using Resurrection Remix Tissot 7.0.1 (Pie) in a Mi-A1 and I'm looking for a way to disable autorefresh on my apps, someone know how to do it?

The "autorefresh" is the function of Android that refresh an app (like Firefox Browser) always you change it from second to first plan, and I see this as a wasting of time, of data, of processing time and of battery life.

If I'm writing something in a comment box on Firefox, for instance, when I change the browser to second plan to confirm some information and come it back to first plan, it refreshs the site automatically and I lose everything I've written.

Comment: Firefox for Android is a buggy piece of software. Its private browsing is worst. One version it was working fine. Then I updated it and suffered the same symptoms mentioned in your question. If the problem is limited to Firefox only, report it to Mozilla. If not, you may be running short on RAM.

Comment: I owned this phone earlier, it had this problem on stock Android 8,AFAIR

Comment: Firelord, it happens on all apps. What are you mean about "running short on RAM"? I believe my RAM is in a normal behaviour.